# Interface Builder and View Hierarchy Construction

Tags: iphone, interface, uiview, uiviewcontroller, interface-builder

I have created a simple UIView hierarchy in IB:

Parent (UIView)
  child (UIView)
  child (UIView)
  child (UIButton)

The button sits atop the two sibling UIViews.

My app launches in landscape mode rather then portrait. When the only child view is a UIButton, the button correctly rotates 90 deg. However, when I add the child UIViews they remain unrotated with the properly rotated UIButton atop them. Wha?

Could someone please tell me how to make all child views created in IB follow the correct orientation behavior.

Cheers,
Doug

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ignore this. In IB there is a curved arrow at the upper right hand corner of the device window graphic that rotates the window 90 deg. Coolness.

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, you should note that when building views that rotate in Interface Builder (or in any fashion, really) it is critical to properly configure the springs and struts using the autosizing control in the size inspector.